# Why doesn't the gpg signature get verified while Ubuntu 16.04 kernel installation?

Tags: 16.04, kernel, gnupg, linux-headers

I'm trying to compile the kernel 'linux-4.15.tar.gz' and I'm following the process for the same. While verifying the gpg signature, the error I'm facing is:
`gpg: no signed data
gpg: can't hash datafile: No data`